# Apostrophe for Noto CJK fonts

Tags: xetex, overleaf, cjk

In my article, I would like to display Traditional Chinese characters.

I'm using the following structure in Overleaf online editor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK TC}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{bsmi}

\textbf{Example 2}

你係老師既學生 (means "You are teacher's student.")

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: screenshot to show the issue]

You might notice that there are some extra spaces after the apostrophe, single & double quotes; and the first double quote is in the incorrect direction. I was thinking it was a font problem. I then change it to `Noto Serif CJK TC`, but the problem still exists.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think it is a combination of a font and an input problem: First of all, `"` always outputs a closing double quotation mark per default and actually, the suggested use is `''` (two straight apostrophes), not `"`. For an opening double quotation mark, use two backticks   \`\`   . As for the space, the glyphs of the font for quotation marks and apostrophes seem to be full-width which is, however, a choice of the font designers to make the quotation marks fit the style of Chinese/Japanese text where every character (and also most punctuation marks) have the same width.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the opening quote issue, for the apostrophe formatting issue, I'm still finding solution.

Comment: If you use `fontspec` and set the fonts language independently like you do, there is actually no need to use the `CJKutf8` package or the `CJK*` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the default way to input quotation marks and apostrophes in LaTeX would rather be:

```
``You are teacher's student.''
```

While this would change the first double quotation mark to an opening one, the spacing issue would still not be resolved this way. The reason for the strange spacing is that the relevant glyphs in the font you chose are designed to be full-width in order to fit the typographical requirements of CJK typesetting where traditionally all glyphs (characters and punctuation marks alike) have the same width.

You can check this with the following code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showcharinbox, anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\ShowCharInBox{\fontsize{200}{210}\selectfont '}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which shows that the apostrophe glyph in this font has a quite wide bounding box:

[image]

---

There are various versions of the Noto CJK fonts available on the Internet, so I don't know whether this works for you. However, the [fonts available on GitHub](https://github.com/notofonts/noto-cjk/tree/main) actually also provide another set of glyphs for quotation marks and apostrophe that are not full-width and which are accessible via OpenType features (using `\addfontfeatures{CharacterWidth=Proportional}` or `\addfontfeatures{CharacterWidth=Full}` for example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK TC}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example 2} \\
你係老師既學生 (means ``You are teacher's student.") 

% set features only for selection
\textbf{Example 2} \\
他說：“你係老師既學生” {\addfontfeatures{CharacterWidth=Proportional} (means ``He says: `You are teacher's student'.")}

% set features globally
\addfontfeatures{CharacterWidth=Proportional}
\textbf{Example 2} \\
你係老師既學生 (means ``You are teacher's student.") 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another way to solve this, could be to use the `xeCJK` package (which only works with XeLaTeX though) that takes care of automatically chosing the right font depending on which characters you input (however, if you look closely, it does not really use the full-width glyphs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans Mono CJK TC}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK TC}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Example 2} \\
他說：“你係老師既學生” (means ``He says: `You are teacher's student'.")

\end{document}
```

[image]